# Format number of decimals based on another column PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Table in my Database that contains values that are of type float8. I want to change these values to only contain decimal places configured in another table without changing the type.

```
CREATE TABLE config (
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    decimals int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT 2,
    CONSTRAINT config PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE event (
    value float8 NOT NULL,
    config_id uuid NOT NULL,
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT event_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT config_id FOREIGN KEY (config_id) REFERENCES config(id)
);
```

My Tables would look like this:

| event |  |  | config |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **id** | **config_id** | **value** | **id** | **decimals** |
| 0 | 1 | 18.891827465774448 | 0 | 2 |
| 1 | 0 | -1.4444289712231306 | 1 | 5 |

I've tried doing it this way

```
ALTER TABLE event 
ALTER COLUMN value TYPE decimal(16, (SELECT config.decimals 
 FROM config, event 
 WHERE config.id = event.config_id));
```

that returns

> ERROR: type modifiers must be simple constants or identifiers

After the Alter Table they should look like this:

| event |  |  | config |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **id** | **config_id** | **value** | **id** | **decimals** |
| 0 | 1 | 18.89182 | 0 | 2 |
| 1 | 0 | -1.44 | 1 | 5 |

Comment: Welcome to SO. Do you really need to change the data type? Wouldn't it suffice to simply truncate / round the decimals in query time?

Comment: 1) I think your output table is wrong, in that the `decimals` does match the values in `value`. 2) This is a mess. You would have to run this every time you changed a `value` in `event`. 3) Why are you throwing away decimal places?  4) If this is what you want it should be done as part of whatever process is inserting/updating the data.

Comment: @JimJones This is supposed to be a migration. New data will be input with with the correct number of decimal places but the old data needs to be updated to the correct values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change the data type per row. Instead, format the numbers in the query. Use [`to_char`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) to format the value and [`repeat`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) to build the format

```
select
  to_char(event.value, '999999999D' || repeat('9', config.decimals)
from event
left join config on config.id = event.config_id
```

Alternatively, leave this formatting up to the application layer.

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out thanks to your help what worked was updating the value with `update event set value = cast(to_char(event.value, '999999999D' || repeat('9', config.decimals))  as float8)
from config
where config.id = event.config_id;` Leaving the formatting to the application is, sadly,  not an option since this was a migration. New values will be formatted before getting saved to the database but old values needed to be updated.

Comment: I don't think that's doing what you think it is. Postgres isn't storing the formatting. You're rounding the number and storing that. This will *mostly* work, but because of the inaccuracy of floating point sometimes it will not. If you use `numeric` instead of `float8` that will avoid the problem.

Comment: Alright I'll change that. Thanks again for the help!